# convert string, with day of week to timestamp

Tags: java

Are there any ways to convert "Wed, 30 Nov 2011 09:13:00" to a timestamp besides programatically coding it yourself?  Like any libraries/functions that can help accomplish this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is your friend in this case

Remember that Date.getTime() returns miliseconds since the beginning of unix time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JODA Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It has format building capabilities for parsing dates and time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

String dateStr = "Wed, 30 Nov 2011 09:13:00";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

formatter.parse(dateStr);

Answer (score -1):

Try [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), more powerful and flexible than JDK